# Help identifying vine in orchid

Tags: orchids

I have a large collection of indoor orchids in good health.  Recently though a strange vine has appeared in one of my indoor orchid pots.  I'm not sure if it's a weed or pest, or some sort of non-invasive companion plants that just happen to like the same conditions as orchids.  My concern is I don't want it to strangle or rob the orchid of nutrients.  So if there's doubt I'll dig em' out!   THANKS very much for the help.

Vine
[image: vine]

Orchid it's trying to cozy up to
[image: orchid]

K

Comment: The photo of the vine is washed out, making it hard to see any details that would help in identifying it.  Could you take another one and post it instead?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a flower genetically modified. Or malformed. This happens often in plants, which have a genetic variability much higher than ours, even in the same individual.

It would be much easier if you put a picture of the whole plant with your "strange vine". And even more pictures. So we could see the size compared to the plant, the exact point from which it grows and in which direction it is growing. Thank you.